# Using XSLT how do we render CDATA tag?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

> Using XSLT how do we render CDATA tag?
>
> In xslt I dont want to create CDATA tag using text or declaring in xml
>   output tag using cdata-section-elements,
>   it should read it dynamically from input, if element value is around CDATA than 
>   then xslt should render the same, as shown below

**Input**:

```
<A><![CDATA[Hello World]]></A>
```

**XSLT Output** :

```
<A><![CDATA[Hello World]]></A>
```

Comment: The great advantage of XSLT in working with XML is that it buffers you as a programmer from cruft like this.  If your design calls for you to be working with XML at the level of the surface syntax, then change your design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data model XSLT/XPath/XQuery operate on does not know any CDATA sections so you can't simply preserve them as the tree you operate on simply contains a text node in both cases (i.e. for `<foo>a &amp; b</foo>` and `<foo><![CDATA[a & b]]></foo>` the tree is a `foo` element containing a single text child node with the string value `a & b`).

So there is no way in pure XSLT to achieve what you want, unless you pre-process the input to convert CDATA sections into some structure like elements the XSLT data model allows you to detect and distinguish. Andrew Welch has http://andrewjwelch.com/lexev/ to do that in a Java environment.

Thus if you use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 with Java you could use that approach.